# How can I install parse for python3 if I get importError?

Tags: python-3.x

So I'm working in Linux and I need to install parse for python3 but always get the same error: ImportError: No module named parse. I tried it:

1. from urllib.parse import urlparse
2. from parser import *
3. try:
   from urllib.parse import urlparse
   except ImportError:
   from urlparse import urlparse (but as I know its only for python2, I work on python3).
   Also tried to do this pip install parse but had no result. Before it I had the next error “NameError: global name 'parse' is not defined”.
   Please can you help me, what should I do? I found that some people have the same problem but their resolutions dont help me

Comment: urllib.parse is in the standard library: https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html You do not need to install anything.

Answer (score 1):

`urllib` is in standard library, no need to install. It works ok for me in python 3.x. Probably you have named your script(the .py file you are running) to `urllib`. This is a common mistake, rename it to something else then it works.

It could happen even if you have a python file named `urllib` in  your directory... because when you run your script, python will automatically add it's directory to `sys.path`(where python searched for modules/packages). So it gets reached sooner than the original `urllib` which is in the standard library.

Search that file in your directory and delete it.

Comment: Hmm i haven’t named my script as urllib and I don’t have no one file with name urllib

Comment: @hsgggs In python 2, it was separate module. https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/urlparse.html . Could you check `print(sys.executable)` to see if it runs correct version of interpreter ?